# Each then() should return a value or throw - promise/always-return in node JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have tried the code from sample code but there is an error while deploying the error is

```
42:7  error  Each then() should return a value or throw  promise/always-return
```

Here is the code

```
db.collection('users').get().then((snapshot) => {
    if (!doc || !doc.exists) {
        throw new Error("data does not exists");
    }
    snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        return  console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
    });
})
.catch((err) => {
    return  console.log('Error getting documents', err);
});
```

Comment: do you want me to put full script here I don't mind as this script is demo

Comment: if snapshot.length is 0 no value is returned

Comment: so, if you have 0 users in db, I think snapshots' length will be 0

Comment: It doesn't matter what the length of snapshot is. No value will ever be returned. It's returning from the function inside of forEach, not the then function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example above you are returning from the forEach function, not the then. I would change it to

```
return snapshot.map(doc => {
   ...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me format that a bit so it becomes more clear to identify the issue:

```
db.collection('users').get()
  .then((snapshot) => {
    if (!doc || !doc.exists) {
      throw new Error("data does not exists");
    }

    snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      return  console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
    });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    return  console.log('Error getting documents', err);
  });
```

As you can see above, the

> .then

is not returning anything because the return inside

> snapshot.forEach

is returning the values for the forEach not for the .then.

Comment: I don't get my friend.

Comment: the forEach has it's own function, which is where you are returning a value. Your then function does not return a value at all.